# Illegal State Exception and Permissions issue when playing default ringtone on android using MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-permissions, illegalstateexception

I have looked at all the other posts on this topic and I have tried all of them  with no avail. I literally just want to play the current ringtone on a loop, if there is an easier way, please let me know.

Here is my current code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        player.setDataSource(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.prepareAsync();                                // this is Line 34
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();
}
```

Everything I try gives me the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
                  at com.package.MainService.onStartCommand(MainService.java:34)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3688)
```

The media player works fine if I give it an mp3 in my /res/raw folder.

I just read further up the console and it says:

```
Couldn't open content://media/external/audio/media/738: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading 
com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri 
content://media/external/audio/media/738 from pid=24931, uid=10295 requires 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : 
           java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading 
com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri 
content://media/external/audio/media/738 from pid=24931, uid=10295 requires 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

**UPDATE**

I just added the permission to the manifest but the issue is still there:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    ...
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Add Runtime permission for Reading Media Files from URI.

From [Documnetation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Add this code in your Activity for Runtime permission:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Comment: That puts it back to the Illegal State. I just read further up in the console and it's saying something about permissions. I will put it in the question.

Comment: Are u testing in sdk > 23? if so you need to add runtime permission for reading media files fro uri...

Comment: I tried to add "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" but it didn't work, is that the one you meant?

Comment: Does anyone know why adding the permission in the manifest doesn't work?

Comment: It it the Android OS behaviour..from Marsmallow you need to ask permission At runtime from the user. Only setting in the Manifest will not work. I have added a documentation link for it.